# Android studio crashes

Tags: android-studio, crash

I am using android-studio in Arch linux 32bit from AUR.Recenty after latest pacman system upgrade , android-studio is refusing to start.Throws this error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x64056842, pid=645, tid=1686977344<br>
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_72-b14) (build 1.7.0_72-b14)<br>
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.72-b04 mixed mode linux-x86 )<br>
Problematic frame:<br>
C  0x64056842<br>

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/joshua/java_error_in_STUDIO_645.log<br>

/usr/bin/android-studio: line 188:   645 Aborted                 (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$IDE_BIN_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$JDK/bin/java" $AGENT "-Xbootclasspath/a:$IDE_HOME/lib/boot.jar" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $VM_OPTIONS "-Djb.vmOptionsFile=$VM_OPTIONS_FILES_USED" "-XX:ErrorFile=$HOME/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log" -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.4 $IDE_PROPERTIES_PROPERTY $IDE_JVM_ARGS $REQUIRED_JVM_ARGS $MAIN_CLASS_NAME "$@"
```

can anybody please suggest me how to fix this issue.Otherwise which package should I rollback so that it could work again?

Answer (score 3):

Same here. I found [this](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/46619) thread to be useful.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libglib-2.0.so studio.sh
```

However it seems like a workaround not a real solution.

EDIT:
Arch users:

`wget http://pkgbuild.com/~heftig/glib2-2.46.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
sudo pacman -U glib2-2.46.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Answer (score 0):

Same error here!
Android studio 1.4.0.10-2
Arch linux 
with jdk 8u60-1

EDIT:

Solved, after I changed the default java environments from java-8-jdk to java-8-openjdk.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to respond to this post.I have similar problem with Android Studio 2.1.0 on linux OS (64 bit), studio crashing frequently . I tried to increase the size of JVM’s Heap by adding to gradle.properties file but it didn't help at all. I have updated java 1.8.0_77 to 1.8.0_92  now Android Studio works fine.